# Increase video *and* audio playback speed without losing quality

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm speeding up a video by 2x with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 50 -vcodec mpeg4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" -filter:a "atempo=2" output.mp4
```

However, the output quality is very low. I used `-r 50` because that's what the Ffmpeg guide recommends ([here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)) in order to avoid frame dropping. What can I do to keep a good quality in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless specified, FFmpeg defaults to a video bitrate of 200k for codec `mpeg4`. So, just override it with a higher value.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" -r 50 -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 1500k -af "atempo=2" out.mp4
```

You may want to skip the `r` option if the content doesn't have very fine motion. You'll achieve better quality at the same bitrate.

Comment: I did it without the `r` option and the result is perfect! Thanks!